# If $a>0,b>0$ show that exists $x,y\in \mathbb{I}$ near to $a,b$ such that $x^y\in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

If $a>0,b>0$ show that exists $x_0,y_0\in \mathbb{I}$ (irrationals) near to $a,b$ respectively such that  $x_0^{y_0} \in \mathbb{Q}$.

I was trying this way: 
Defining the function $f(x,y)=x^y$, $x\neq 1$, I know that if $Df_{(x_0,y_0)}\neq 0$ and $f(x_0,y_0)=0 \ \ (\star)$, then exists open sets $W,V$ with $x_0\in V$, and a diffeomorphism $\phi$ such that:
$$ (f\circ \phi)(x_0,y_0)=y_0 \ \ (\star \star) $$

I don't have the condition $(\star)$, however, I think the result is valid if $f(x_0,y_0)=c$, with $c$ constant. Although I do not know if this way's a good idea, also do not see how the conclusion.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does near mean? For every $\epsilon>0$ there are $x,y$ irrationals with $|x-a|+|y-b|<\epsilon$ and $x^y$ rational?

Comment: @Andres Caicedo, I suppose. The question is not clear, but should be $|x-a|<\varepsilon$ and $|y-b|<\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can easily prove a stronger statement: that for every irrational $x_0>0$ and open set $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists a $y_0\in U$ with $x_0^{y_0}$ rational. This follows since $\log_{x_0}$ is a continuous surjective function from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (note $x_0 \neq 1$) and so maps $\mathbb{Q}^+$ to a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$.